# How to export serialized data from Wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress, excel, serialization, export

I use Advanced Custom Fields and ACF Repeater field plugins for Wordpress, and I'm having problems getting serialized data in SQL and Excel.

I build a base of children for Russian medical institutions. It was planned so worker from institution can add child to database and add services that child got there. So these are [checkboxes for services](https://yadi.sk/d/_6SEkMP3V3cQC).
Key function for me is repeater field, which allows to create new amount of services.

Close to the problem. In database it is saved serialized, like [this](https://yadi.sk/d/V4OiXtalV3d4o). I export posts and meta to Excel using an SQL query and I get this serialized data there too. Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
post_title
,(SELECT meta_value FROM kr_postmeta WHERE kr_postmeta.meta_key = 'birth_day' AND kr_postmeta.post_id = kr_posts.ID) as "birth_day"
FROM kr_posts
WHERE post_type = 'post' 
GROUP BY post_title
ORDER BY post_title DESC
```

And I can’t even say what I expect to see as a solution, all of them seem to be impracticable. It might be:

- Changing way of writing multiple data in ACF, so I don't get serialized data.
- Enhance export to get unserialized data.
- Unserialize data in CSV file.

Comment: Can you use PHP to wrap the SQL and do the unserialization?